# Best and simple way to call .net assemblies in java

Tags: c#, java, .net, migration

Exists a way to call .net assemblies more specific .dll files in java?

I i'm developing a a framework for .net now i need to migrate it to java, i can do this? I using c#  in .net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check is this response is helpful..
[Calling .net assembly from java jvm crashes..](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138355/calling-net-assembly-from-java-jvm-crashes)

Came across this interesting site (may not be directly helpful to you)...

[dotnetfromjava.dev.java.net](https://dotnetfromjava.dev.java.net/)

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way should be to COM-enable the .Net assembly. This way you can invoke any method the way you would communicate with normal WIN32 DLL's.

Some samples can be found here: http://www.devx.com/interop/Article/19845

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for COM objects and I would not recommend any custom solutions as it would be like reinventing the wheel. There are a lot of specific cases and details about such integration that would come up like passing by "ref", "out", generic methods etc.etc... the best I would suggest is to use JAVA to .NET bridge like [www.javonet.com](http://www.javonet.com).

Here is short article about this solution:
http://javabridges.hubpages.com/hub/Using-NET-libraries-from-JAVA-is-that-possible

There are also other such bridges but with javonet you get very easy API that with one JAR file you can just copy your .NET dll and call it directly without any additional steps. It supports .NET exceptions, object disposing, calling instance and static methods including generics, setting/getting fields and lot more... You work with .NET dll objects in java like they were native JAVA class.

Usage Sample is like:

```
//Sample Usage of .NET Random Class from JAVA using Javonet
NObject dotNetRandom = Javonet.New("System.Random");
Integer randomNumber = dotNetRandom.invoke("Next",5,10);
```

Please notice that such bridge automatically translates results to native JAVA types if possible and the same way with methods arguments. A lot of samples you can read in quick start guide on Javonet website.